# sinatra put method is not working

Tags: sinatra

Hi on submission of the form 'put' method is used to send data from form to sinatra.the put method is defined in app.rb put method makes a call to erb file which displays the two values.

but nothing is being displayed could somebody help please.

```
put '/form' do

@name = params[:FirstName]
@last = params[:LastName]

erb :formact
end
```

form

```
<form name="biodata" action="form" method="put" onsubmit="validateForm()">
code
</form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `PUT` is a valid method for form submission. Check your HTTP server log and see if the requests are actually coming as `PUT` requests -- the browser might be sending them as `GET`, which is the default.

Anyway, you should probably just use `POST` instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can't send a `PUT` request directly from a browser, but you can fake it using Sinatra's [`method_override`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__enabledisable_the_post__hack) option, which is set to true by default in classic style. If you’re using modular style you’ll have to enable it with `enable :method_override`.

This checks incoming requests for a parameter named `_method`, and if it finds one the request method of the call is changed to the parameter's value so it appears to the rest of the app that the call was made using that HTTP method.

The way to get your `put` method to work is to use the `POST` method in your form, but to include a hidden input with name "_method" and value "put"

```html
<form name="biodata" action="form" method="post" onsubmit="validateForm()">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
  code
</form>
```

This is the same technique that is used in Rails (in fact it's the same middleware that's used - `Rack::MethodOverride`).